# How to use 'make' with GHC Dependency Generation

Tags: haskell, makefile, ghc

I've got a couple of (independent) files that take quite a while to compile, so I thought I would try out parallel compilation, per Don Stewart's answer [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg57731.html).

I followed the directions [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#makefile-dependencies), so my makefile looks something like

```
quickbuild:
    ghc --make MyProg.hs -o MyProg

depend:
    ghc -M -dep-makefile makefile MyProg

# DO NOT DELETE: Beginning of Haskell dependencies
...
MyProg.o : MyProg.hs
MyProg.o : B.hi
MyProg.o : C.hi
...
# DO NOT DELETE: End of Haskell dependenciesghc
```

(Note: contrary to [the docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#makefile-dependencies), GHC seems to default to "Makefile" rather than "makefile", even when "makefile" exists.)

My question is: How do I make quickbuild depend on any of the auto-gen dependencies (so that make will actually run in parallel)? I tried adding 'MyProg.o' to the dependency list of 'quickbuild', but 'make' (rightly) complained that there was no rule to build 'B.hi'.

Comment: Obviously I'm trying to avoid making a build statement for every file, which would be annoying at the very best. I don't *think* that's what Don intended, but it isn't clear what I should do instead.

Comment: Can you just make a pseudo-rule (or whatever make calls it) for `*.hi` files...?

Comment: Are you suggesting adding: `B.hi: B.o\n\t ghc B`? Then I'd need to do that for all 40 modules. Did you mean something else?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting adding something like `%.hi: %.hs\n\tghc $^`. But I don't remember all the syntax off the top of my head, so be sure to look in make's fine manual.

Comment: Oh, cool! I'm not familiar with that syntax at all, but I'll take a look.

Comment: [Here's the relevant section of the GNU make manual.](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) Apparently they're called "pattern rules", not pseudo-rules.

Comment: You can write that up as an answer. I'm having mixed success overall with parallel make: it tends to die halfway through with an error "Foo.o: getFileStatus: does not exist (No such file or directory)", so I have to run 'make' repeatedly.

Comment: I suggest not to use Make for this kind of purpose. Look at [ghc-parmake](https://github.com/23Skidoo/ghc-parmake) and its issues - GHC has a very sophisticated recompilation checker that you cannot replicate with Makefiles (it can detect e.g. if a package file outside of your own project changes). You will also not receive a large speedup (in practice not > 2) from using `make -j` for running multiple GHCs in parallel - firing multiple GHCs has high startup overhead which is avoided by `ghc --make`. Instead, use the new `ghc --make -j` of GHC 7.8 - it is truly parallel.

Comment: @nh2 Thanks! You should write that up as an answer. Now I just have to wait for GHC 7.8...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not to use `make` for this kind of purpose.

Look at [ghc-parmake](https://github.com/23Skidoo/ghc-parmake) and its issues, [especially this one](https://github.com/23Skidoo/ghc-parmake/issues/9) - GHC has a very sophisticated recompilation checker that you cannot replicate with Makefiles (it can detect e.g. if a package file outside of your own project changes).

You will also not receive a large speedup (in practice not > 2) from a parallel `make -j` for running multiple GHCs in parallel, since firing multiple GHCs has high startup overhead which is avoided by `ghc --make`. In particular, each new GHC invocation has to parse and typecheck all the interface `.hi` files involved in all dependencies of the module you are compiling; `ghc --make` caches them.

Instead, use the new `ghc --make -j` of GHC 7.8 - it is truly parallel.

It will be more reliable and less effort than your manually written Makefile, and do [recompilation avoidance](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/RecompilationAvoidance) better than Make can do with its file time stamps.

---

On the first view, this sounds like a drawback of Haskell, but in fact it is not. In other languages that like to use `make` for building, say C++, it is impossible to notice when files outside of your project change; having a build system in the compiler itself like `ghc --make` allows to notice this.